# Are the order of contract names inside override important?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

Are the order of contract names inside override important?

For example, in contract `Z`, is

`function foo() override(X, Y) {... }` same as
`function foo() override(Y, X) {... }`?

Or do they convey a different meaning?

```
contract X {
    function foo() public pure virtual returns (string memory) {
        return "X";
    }
}

contract Y is X {
    function foo() public pure virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return "Y";
    }
}

contract Z is X, Y {
    function foo() public pure override(X, Y) returns (string memory) {
        return "Z";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think yes it is https://solidity-by-example.org/inheritance/

Comment: but why you inheritance  from X and Y?  because Y inheritance already from X

Comment: @MajdTL For example, chain of inheritance may not be obvious. It might be 
A -> B -> D
and
A -> C -> D

The example above is simplied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the order in the `override` specifier does not matter at all. The order in which virtual functions are considered by `super` is determined by inheritance order and you cannot change it by reordering contracts in `override`.

This is confusing to many users because people really expect that changing it means something. This is why in one of the future releases the compiler may actually start requiring the same order as on the inheritance list (see [#8354](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/8373)).